# I use recycle view and Picasso but when update data to recycle view picasso not load picture android

Tags: android, image, load, picasso

Picasso is not loading image. 
Here is my code screen shot:

[image]

When i scroll in recycle image is not smooth
Hope everyone help me

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Make other view also visible. i.e. `holder.txtMessage.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);` in if block and same way `holder.imgPic`

Comment: https://github.com/thangvynam/Android-/tree/master/AppChat/app/src/main here

Comment: i dont understand when i post text message  , nothing happens but i post image when image not load and hidden many item text message . So u see all item , you must restart app . Hope you help em . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can add smooth scroller for smooth scrolling in recyclerview. You have to follow below steps:

1) Just create smooth scroller.

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
    @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
         return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
    }
};
```

2) Set smooth scroller to layout manager like below.

```
layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Now all set!!

Your recyclerview will be scrolled smoothly.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I dont know put what context is

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your code and set fixed height for image view if not image view taking height as 0 and size will increase after load the image

```
if(message.getMessageType().equals(MesageType.Text)){
    holder.imgPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtMessage.setText(message.getMessageText());
}else{
    holder.imgPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.txtMessage.setText("");
    Picasso.with(context).load(message.getUrl_downloadd()).into(holder.imgPic);
}
```

**Firebase listeners:**

```
/*Child listener for chat*/
private final ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapShot, String s) {
        //append the message to exiting an displayed
        if (snapShot != null && snapShot.getValue() != null && !snapShot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("users")) {
            Message message = snapShot.getValue(Message.class);
            if (message != null && !messageKeys.contains(snapShot.getKey())) {
                messageKeys.add(snapShot.getKey());
                message.setKey(snapShot.getKey());
                //add your new message to adapter
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapShot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapShot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
//value added listener for chat
private final ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        if (data != null && data.getValue() != null && data.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
            /*add all  messages to lis and displayed*/

            for (DataSnapshot snapShot : data.getChildren()) {
                if (snapShot != null && snapShot.getValue() != null && !snapShot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("users")) {
                    Message message = snapShot.getValue(Message.class);
                    if (message != null && !messageKeys.contains(snapShot.getKey())) {
                        messageKeys.add(snapShot.getKey());
                        message.setKey(snapShot.getKey());
                        messages.add(message);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
     //display your message on adapter

        //removed ValueEventListener from firebase
             getQueryForMessages().removeEventListener(this);
        //added child change listener to firebase
                   getQueryForMessages().addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

Comment: i dont set height picture but old pictures are still exist , only new picture is posted hidden

Comment: i had post code in a comment 
github.com/thangvynam/Android-/tree/master/AppChat/app/src/main

Comment: yes , I finally found the reason for lack of scroll ,you are added the list item one by one and notified each time that's it's getting lacked. so use event listener instead of child listener .

Comment: that's mean i should use addValueEventListener instead of addChildEventListener . But I really dont know difference between addValueEventListener and addChildEventListener  . U can explain me ?

Comment: yes, ValueEventListener  will return all children so you can iterate it then  added to your own list and you can set to your adapter. ChildEventListener will trigger for each child.

Comment: 1)add ValueEventListener read all chi8ldern and loaded to your adapter

Comment: I use ValueEventListener  but I cant take message only take null object